# Need to write and read exchange freebusy information

Tags: interop, exchange-server

Can anyone help me to read and write exchange free/busy information similar to Google Calendar interop?

Comment: Probably, but you'll have to give them something to work with first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, and edit your question to include more information as well as a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions should be asked about specific issues you have with code you're writing, with examples provided, not simply asking for help, advice or tutoring on a given topic.

Answer (score 1):

The free/busy time option on Microsoft Exchange is generated from the Outlook/Exchange Calendar entries from the users. These info's are fetched from the users calendar by the Availability service as written by Microsoft [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134(v=exchg.150).aspx). So if you wish to "SET" something, you need to create an calendar entry for the user. If you try to add something to the backend environment which is managed by Microsoft Exchange you might cause issues for the users as they do not see that in there calendars. So please create a calendar entry for your purpose and let the MS Exchange Availability service do the rest.

A good starting point to understand the construct is:

- [Availability service in Exchange 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232134(v=exchg.150).aspx)